# java.lang.IllegalStateException after invalidate session and trying to create new session in JBoss EAP 7.0.0

Tags: jboss-eap-7

All,

I am consistently getting java.lang.IllegalStateException when dealing with HTTP sessions in JBoss EAP 7.0.0. Here is the scenario ...

1) Session created and I printed session id 
HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);

2) Session got invalidated sess.invalidate()

3) When I print session id it is same as in step 1) moreover I should not get 
session object after invalidate instead should get null.
HttpSession sess2 = request.getSession(false);
Surprisingly sess2 is NOT null and returning ID same as step 1)

Please note that above worked in JBoss 7.1.0 Beta and would like to know any regression issues in JBoss EAP 7.0.0 related to session invalidation etc.

I believe this is easy to reproduce with 7.0.0 EAP, however I can provide detailed logs if needed to prove above buggy behavior.

Thanks & Regards,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified whether or not this is an issue with the latest 7.0.x release?

Comment: It is indeed an issue with 7.0 because it worked with 7.1 beta.